# An idiomatic, guaranteed mutex in C# for a data structure?

Tags: c#, locking

Suppose in C# you have a `Dictionary<K, V>` object that multiple threads are accessing and changing.  You want certain operations to be thread-safe.

So you reach for a mutex.  In C#, the standard way to use a mutex is:

```
lock (someSharedObject)
{
   // Mutual exclusion zone here.
   myDictionary.Add(1, "hello");
}
```

The problem is, you're relying merely on documentation to keep future programmers from accessing the dictionary directly, bypassing the mutex:

```
myDictionary.Add(1, "hello");
```

I want the compiler to prevent a future programmer from using the unprotected dictionary.

I see two general possibilities:

1. Create a Dictionary lookalike (say, `LockedDictionary`) which ensures locking in its member methods but acts like a Dictionary in every other way.
2. Create a class that guards access to the `Dictionary`, so the caller cannot reach the `Dictionary` without going through the guard.

These fulfill the desireable property that now no one can use the dictionary unprotected, at least accidentally.  I want to discuss the pros and cons of both, and then ask you to agree or disagree with me as well as to suggest a solution I may have overlooked.

The upside of `LockedDictionary` is that it's intuitive for others.  It also allows fine-grained control of which methods need locking and to what extent.  The downside is that it's not exactly a `Dictionary`, so you cannot pass this object to a function that expects to receive a `Dictionary`.  (Though you can get close by implementing `IDictionary`.)

Moving on to #2. The upside of a guard class is that you can implement `IDisposable` and use it like this:

```
class DictionaryFortress {
   Dictionary<K, V> realDict;
   Object lockobject;
   void Lock() {
      Monitor.Enter(lockobject);
      return DictionaryGuard(lockobject, realDict);
   }
}

class DictionaryGuard : IDisposable {
   public Dictionary<K, V> Dict {
      get { return realDict; }
   }
   public void Dispose() {
      Monitor.Exit(lockobject);
   }
}

// in some class
DictionaryFortress dict = new DictionaryFortress(); // early on

// in a function, when we need to access dictionary contents...
using (DictionaryGuard guard = dict.Lock()) {
   Dictionary<K, V> actualDict = guard.Dict;
   // now you can pass actualDict anywhere; no one has to know that it's locked
}
```

The upside, of course, is that we have access to the raw dictionary, so we're not constrained in how we can use it and where we can pass it.  The downside is that there's more overhead in using it.  It's also possible for a user to save a reference to `guard.Dict` while it's available, then use it after DictionaryGuard is disposed.

I am leaning toward #2.  Did I miss any pros and cons?  Is there a better way of protecting access to my dictionary while minimizing the risk of misuse? Again, my *requirement* is that a forgetful or careless programmer cannot skip the locking stage.  My desirements are that it's idiomatic, convenient, and flexible.

Comment: Have you considered [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)?

Comment: or ConcurrentBag, ConcurrentQueue, and ConcurrentStack for other thread-safe collections. No point in reinventing the wheel...

Comment: Thank you. While I knew that surely I am reinventing the wheel, I forgot about the existence of these. Would you post this as a proposed answer?

Comment: Done. It was introduced in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)? It, and the other [concurrent collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108.aspx) were introduced in .NET 4.0.

> Represents a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be
>   accessed by multiple threads concurrently.